# How to publish a full website without compiling and without copying SVN files

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, publishing, vs-web-site-project

Apparently, DNN installations do not like to be precompiled (they won't be able to find any localized strings then). Our installation is safely put in SVN, which means I cannot just copy the whole directory. To publish everything, I need to copy the whole website directory *without the SVN files and directories*. So far, I've been messing with good old DOS commands, which is time consuming and error prone.

Can someone help me to an MS-Built script or step to do just this? Or can I do this using default Visual Studio 2010 commands?

Note: this is a *website*, not a *web application*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Visual Studio` -> `Solution Explorer` -> `<web site>` -> `<right click>` -> `Publish Web Site` or `Copy Web Site`

Comment: Great! Now I feel silly. In retrospect, I think I was aware of this option, but totally forgot about it. Exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

Just `svn export` the directory from source control, which will give you a clean copy without the `.svn` stuff in it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are ever interested in automating this with MSBuild then you can do that with something like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <ItemGroup>
    <FilesToCopy Include="**\*"
                 Exclude="**\.svn\**"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <Dest>C:\temp\dest\</Dest>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="CopyFiles">
    <Message Text="FilesToCopy: @(FilesToCopy)"/>
    <MakeDir Directories="$(Dest)"/>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(FilesToCopy)"
          DestinationFiles="@(FilesToCopy->'$(Dest)%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"/>
  </Target>

</Project>
```

So when I create the `FilesToCopy` item I exclude all the files under any .svn folder. Then I just perform the copy inside the CopyFiles target.