# How do I avoid unnecessary dll recompilation after adding MVC3 views?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, publish

I have an Asp.net MVC3 customer portal application with a view folder hierarchy which allows me to brand each customer by putting new razor views into a Views/Custom folder. For example, this would allow me to create a custom wrapper and landing page for customer "Acme":

```
Views/Custom/Acme/Shared/_Layout.cshtml
Views/Custom/Acme/Home/Index.cshtml
```

The issue I'm having is that creating customized views is far more common than modifications to the application's controllers. However, when I add a new view under the Custom directory and publish my changes, the application's dlls are getting rebuilt.

I'm having problems with shadow copies on my production server and have to take the entire site down when I deploy new dlls (a separate issue, but one I'm resigned to avoid for now).

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio 2010 that adding folders and razor templates do not require the dlls to be recompiled? The Custom folder has Namespace Provider set to True and the Razor templates in each subdirectory are marked as Content, Do Not Copy.

[image: Actual Folder Structure]

Comment: This will probably help you, it also demonstrates how to do it in MSBUild http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500035/how-to-publish-a-full-website-without-compiling-and-without-copying-svn-files

Comment: @DavidMartin I know how to do a publish. That's not what I'm having trouble with. The problem is that it recompiles the dlls when no compiled code was changed.

Comment: I understand your issue, pubilsh always recompiles, I don't know how to avoid that which is why I didn't put my comment as an answer, simply because it doesn't directly answer your question. However the answers for the question linked indicate that you could copy files rather than publish, or publish just named files, both of which would skip the files that had been recompiled.

Comment: @DavidMartin But if I change an existing xml template, it doesn't recompile the dlls. I have my publish settings configured to `Replace matching files with local copies`.